# Macintosh IIci not booting

Tags: hardware, apple-macintosh

I have an old Macintosh IIci that worked until a few weeks ago but now doesn't turn on anymore.

When I press the power button on the keyboard all the lights on the keyboard and the one on the main case flash but nothing else happens. When I keep the button held the fan turns on at some point and the lights flash repeatedly.

I have taken out the power supply but all the caps seem fine. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated!

Comment: Closest match troubleshooting guide I found online is for the IIsi, which is pretty similar http://www.applerepairmanuals.com/the_manuals_are_in_here/Macintosh_IIsi.pdf

Comment: Thanks @BrianH! I also found https://manuall.co.uk/apple-macintosh-iici-desktop-computer/ and http://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/computing/apple_hardware_devnotes/Mac%20IIci.pdf

Comment: Also see [Apple Technical Procedures Macintosh IIci](https://www.apple.asimov.net/documentation/macintosh/atp_macintoshiici.pdf) If the PSU were good and you had a speaker installed you might expect [beep codes](https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/LIS/Apple_Computer_Beep_Codes). See Macintosh IIci Schematic (bomarc).pdf (7.2 MB) from [Macintosh68kSchematics.tar.bz2](https://archive.org/download/Macintosh68kSchematics/Macintosh68kSchematics.tar.bz2) (64.9 MB). [Macintosh 68k Schematics by Bomarc Services](https://archive.org/details/Macintosh68kSchematics) on the Internet Archive.

Comment: [Apple quadra 700.mac iicx.iici Service Manual](https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/1777063/download/) which would tell you to swap the power supply then the logic board, not particularly useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from experience that the Caps on the Mainboard itself nowadays are mostly bad, leaky and thus need replacement before the electrolyte causes additional damage to the board. The same applies to the Cache Card (if installed). Doing this will most likely bring the machine back to life.

The IIcx, IIci and Q700 share the same PSU, at least from the pinout. From multiple machines I've had, the PSU was never the fault. However, I suggest to disassemble the PSU also and look for about-to-break solder spots, to be on the safe side. Weak points usually are big and/or heavy things (main caps, switching transistor, probably more), as well as components becoming considerably warm when used. Usually visible through a brownish tint around the components.

This description is from my memory. The last IIci recap I did is around 10 years ago, so I can't recall much detail.

Comment: I'll recap the mainboard and post if it helped but it might take a while.